# Topological Spaces and closed sets

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

If someone could look over this answer and let me know if I need to change anything it would be much appreciated!

I have posted the question along with my solution!

[image: Question2]

[image: Solution]

Answer (score 0):

The argument is essentially correct: $f^{-1}[A] = X\setminus f^{-1}[Y\setminus A]$ is closed when $A$ is closed and $f$ continuous. And the same can be said with $A$ open and $f$ preserving inverse images of closed sets.